# Entity framework is super slow with owned collections

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, pgadmin-4, owned-types

These are my models:

**Account**

```
public enum AccountType { Company, User }

public class Account
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)] //Composite key with AccountType
    public long IdCompanyOrUser { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)] //Composite key with IdCompanyOrUser
    public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string? Hash { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<RefreshToken>? RefreshTokens { get; set; } 

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<LoginAttempt>? LoginAttempts { get; set; }
}
```

**Refreshtoken**

```
[Owned]
public class RefreshToken
{
    [Key]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Revoked { get; set; }
    public string? RevokedBy { get; set; }
    public string? ReasonRevoked { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpired => DateTime.UtcNow >= Expires;
    public bool IsRevoked => Revoked != null;
    public bool IsActive => !IsRevoked && !IsExpired;
}
```

**LoginAttempt**

```
public enum FailReason { WrongUserOrPassword, UserInactive, CompanyExpired, CountryRestriction, NoRoleAssigned }
    [Owned]
    public class LoginAttempt
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Ip { get; set; }
        public FailReason? FailReason { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my DB context

```
public class AuthDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasKey(table => new {
            table.IdCompanyOrUser,
            table.AccountType
        });
    }
}
```

When I run this query

```
Account? account = FindSingleOrDefault(x => x.IdCompanyOrUser == id & (int)x.AccountType == accountTypeInt);
```

I am using the design pattern repository so this makes a call to

```
protected readonly DbContext Context;
private DbSet<TEntity> _entities;
public Repository(DbContext context)
{
    Context = context;
    _entities = context.Set<TEntity>();
}

 public TEntity FindSingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) => _entities.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
```

The request takes up to 3 seconds to retrieve the account and around 3000 refresh tokens and 200 login attempts. Which I find too long for such a small amount of records.

I was checking my logs and this is the query that EF core translates from my expression. (the 93 and the 0 are filled by me. These are the parameters). I tested it directly in pgadmin and it takes around the same.

```
SELECT t."IdCompanyOrUser", t."AccountType", t."Hash", l."Id", l."AccountIdCompanyOrUser", l."AccountType", l."FailReason", l."Ip", l."Success", l."Time", r."Id", r."AccountIdCompanyOrUser", r."AccountType", r."Created", r."Expires", r."ReasonRevoked", r."Revoked", r."RevokedBy", r."Token"
FROM (
    SELECT a."IdCompanyOrUser", a."AccountType", a."Hash"
    FROM "Account" AS a
    WHERE (a."IdCompanyOrUser" = 93) AND (a."AccountType" = 0)
    LIMIT 2
) AS t
LEFT JOIN "LoginAttempt" AS l ON (t."IdCompanyOrUser" = l."AccountIdCompanyOrUser") AND (t."AccountType" = l."AccountType")
LEFT JOIN "RefreshToken" AS r ON (t."IdCompanyOrUser" = r."AccountIdCompanyOrUser") AND (t."AccountType" = r."AccountType") 
ORDER BY t."IdCompanyOrUser", t."AccountType", l."Id"
```

I tested two separate queries on my database for getting the login attempts and another one for the refresh tokens and they are pretty quick (60 ms). **Does someone know why it is so slow? Is there a way to optimize it?**

I would like to keep the current implementation where refresh tokens and login attempts are `[owned]` by an account. It is my first time using owned entity types, so I am not sure if I am implementing it correctly and if I understand how they are meant to be used. I would appreciate some feedback and help if possible :)

PS: I am using ET core 6.

Comment: Are the join and filter columns indexed? Which EF Core version are you using? You can tell EF Core to use multiple queries instead of a single one

Comment: Besides, your own code is telling EF to use `LIMIT 1` by using `Queryable.FirstOrDefault()`. There's no other way to return a single root result *and* all related rows in a single query. If you know there's only one matching row you could remove `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: What does `FindSingleOrDefault` ? I suspect if you used `db.Accounts.Include(a=>a.RefreshTokens).Include(a=>a.LoginAttempts).Find(93,0)` the query wouldn't have `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for your answer. I am using ET core 6 and FindSingleOrDefault is a call to another method (I am using repository pattern). Also, I changed the limit 1. ET actually translated It first as limit 2. I changed to see if it had any influence. 

PS: I made all these changes to my question.

Comment: Try to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault` also try to add `AsSplitQuery()`

Comment: @srzsanti we can't guess what your method does. `I am using repository pattern` that doesn't explain much. A DbContext is already a multi-entity repository. At best, that method is an alias for `.FirstOrDefault()`. Most SO questions that use a "repository" over EF Core have serious design problems. As for `ET actually translated It first as limit 2.` that's by design. `SingleOrDefault` will throw if there are more than 1 results. The cheapest way to check that is to ask for two results instead of 1.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you very much. The suggestion of using SplitQuery solved the problem. Now it takes 35ms instead! :) Feel free to answer the question directly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for taking your time. Since yesterday I already edited the question to add the method that ```FindSingleOrDefault ``` was calling. And about the limit 2 or 1 it ended being using FirstOrDefault instead of SingleOrDefault as @SvyatoslavDanyliv suggested. However, this didn't actually have any influence on the speed of the query. Thank you anyway for taking the time and sorry if the question was not completely well explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Eager Loading introduces Cartesian Explosion of master-detail records. EF Core loads everything into memory and then provides records deduplication. If count of the records is huge it may cause dramatical performance degradation.

Starting from EF Core 5 there is operator `AsSplitQuery()` which changes this behavior and loads master-details records by separate queries.

For further reading: [Split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries-1)